# Generating a Plotly Heat Map from a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, plotly, heat

I've been searching this topic for a couple hours now, and still can't get my code to work.  I am trying to generate a heat map from a pivot table I've created using pandas. I'm very new to coding and am probably not using the right terminology, but I'll try my best.

My table looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBJyB.png)

It has many more rows as well.  I am trying to generate a plotly heat map with the countries on the y axis, the 4 ownership types on the x, and the numeric values being used as the z values.  I've been getting a lot of errors, but I think I'm getting close because it gets to my last line and says "TypeError: Object of type 'DataFrame' is not JSON serializable."  I've searched this error but can't find anything that I can understand.  I set up the table like so, and am having trouble with the z, x, and y inputs:

```
data = [go.Heatmap(z=[Country_Ownership_df[['Company Owned', 'Franchise', 'Joint Venture', 'Licensed']]],
                   y=[Country_Ownership_df['Country']],
                   x=['Company Owned', 'Franchise', 'Joint Venture', 'Licensed'],
                   colorscale=[[0.0, 'white'], [0.000001, 'rgb(191, 0, 0)'], [.001, 'rgb(209, 95, 2)'], [.005, 'rgb(244, 131, 67)'], [.015, 'rgb(253,174,97)'], [.03, 'rgb(249, 214, 137)'], [.05, 'rgb(224,243,248)'], [0.1, 'rgb(116,173,209)'], [0.3, 'rgb(69,117,180)'], [1, 'rgb(49,54,149)']])]

layout = go.Layout(
    margin = dict(t=30,r=260,b=30,l=260),
    title='Ownership',
    xaxis = dict(ticks=''),
    yaxis = dict(ticks='', nticks=0 )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
#iplot(fig)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename= 'tempfig3.html')
```

It's probably a fairly simple task, I just haven't learned much with coding and appreciate any help you could offer.

Answer (score 15):

Plotly takes the data arguments as lists, and doesn't support Pandas DataFrames. To get a DataFrame that is already in a correct format,

1. data as the values ('z' in Plotly notation),
2. x-values as columns
3. y-values as index

The following function works:

```
def df_to_plotly(df):
    return {'z': df.values.tolist(),
            'x': df.columns.tolist(),
            'y': df.index.tolist()}
```

As it returns a `dict`, you can directly pass it as an argument to `go.HeatMap`:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(df_to_plotly(df)))
fig.show()
```

Comment: what I did: 'z': mydf["counts"], 'x': mydf["something"], 'y': mydf["other"] inside the df_to_plotly.

Comment: This helped me with one difference, there's no need for `.tolist()` for the `z` axis.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently Plotly doesn't directly support DataFrames.  But you can turn your DataFrames into dictionaries of lists like this:

```
Country_Ownership_df[['foo', 'bar']].to_dict()
```

Then non-Pandas tools like Plotly should work, because dicts and lists are JSON serializable by default.